# Sending an NSURLRequest to phpMyAdmin results in the NSData being the php source code

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, phpmyadmin

I have had quite the night trying to solve problems after "Upgrading" to OS X Yosemite 10.6.6. After re-installing MySQL / phpMyAdmin / Apache / php5 I am still having problems with code that worked before the upgrade. The following function sends a URL request to a locally hosted php file to obtain data from a MySQL data base in a JSON parable format:

```
-(NSArray*) GetJSONArrayForURL:(NSString*)url
{
// Download the json file
NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

// Create the request
//NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];
NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];

NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSData *rawdata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSMutableData *downloaded = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[downloaded appendData:rawdata];

// Parse the JSON that came in
NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:downloaded options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

return jsonArray;
}
```

However, the raw data returned is the source code of the PHP file it is requesting:

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost";
$databaseName = "GUESTLISTER";
$userName = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$POST = "POST";
$GET = "GET";

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect($serverName,$userName,$password,$databaseName);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
 $sql = $_GET['query'];
$action = $_GET['action'];

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($con); 
    if($action == $GET)
    {
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
// to hold the data
$resultArray = array();
$tempArray = array();

// Loop through each row in the result set
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    // Add each row into our results array
    $tempArray = $row;
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}

// Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
else if ($action == $POST)
{
    echo $id;
}
}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The request which is:

http://localhost/webservice.php?&username=admin&password=guestlister123&query=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20users&action=GET

Runs fine when pinged from a web browser, but for some bizarre reason the source code is returned as data when requested from Xcode.

Please advise,
Ryan

Comment: So is this an xcode issue or php issue? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when the same source code is returned instead of its output, it points to the issue that Php is not getting parsed as Php. That means there is an issue with the setup for your webserver - Apache since its unable to process Php. There can be many different reasons for this, a few of them can be

- Apache is off and may need to be turned on, which since outside the xcode it works then that may not be the case
- Apache configuration for Php is not set up correctly
- The website is not in the folder where Apache expects it to be. htdocs is usually the default where Apache looks for php scripts depending on the php.ini configuration. A quickest way is to run the [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php); in a php file between the starting and ending php tags to determine if all is well with your setup.

> phpinfo();

If its set up correctly you would see an output page with all the information about your php and apache setup else it will just give you back the phpinfo() line as output. Finally it could just be that Xcode is not working properly with your Apache setup thus it can be beneficial to directly run scripts through the browser instead of within Xcode which I have never tried.